# The prob. distribution of sum of two independent random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have two Random variables $X,Y$, They are independent. In which, $X,Y$ follows same distribution

$$P(X=1)=P(Y=1)=0.1$$
$$P(X=2)=P(Y=2)=0.4$$
$$P(X=4)=P(Y=4)=0.3$$
$$P(X=10)=P(Y=10)=0.2$$

> How can I find the prob. distribution of event $A$, with $A=X+Y$?

For clearly, I got a special distribution such as

$$p_{X}=p_{Y}=
        \bigl( \begin{matrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 10 & 11 &40 \\ 
                        0.00971  & 0.458 & 0.21 & 0.113 & 0.111 & 0.0797 & 0.0156\end{matrix} \bigr)$$

How can I find the prob. distribution of $S=X+Y$. Is it possible using MATLAB? I think it looks like convolution operation

Hence, this is my code

```
X=1:1:40;
P1=zeros(1, length(X));
P1(1)=0.00971;
P1(2)=0.458;
P1(3)=0.21;
P1(4)=0.113;
P1(10)=0.111;
P1(11)=0.0797;
P1(40)=0.0156;
P2=P1;
conv2(P1,P2)
```

The result is

```
ans =

  Columns 1 through 15

    0.0001    0.0089    0.2138    0.1946    0.1476    0.0475    0.0128         0         0    0.0022    0.1032    0.1196    0.0586    0.0180         0

  Columns 16 through 30

         0         0         0    0.0123    0.0177    0.0064         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0

  Columns 31 through 45

         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0    0.0003    0.0143    0.0066    0.0035         0         0

  Columns 46 through 60

         0         0         0    0.0035    0.0025         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0

  Columns 61 through 75

         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0         0

  Columns 76 through 79

         0         0         0    0.0002
```

Finally, I think the result is

$$p_{X+Y}=
        \bigl( \begin{matrix} 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & \dots &80\\ 
                        0.0001 &   0.0089 &   0.2138  &  0.1946 &   0.1476 &   0.0475 &   &   0.0002    \end{matrix} \bigr)$$

Comment: With the convolution of the two distributions. Ask master Google about it. Edit: Here right at the start http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/Chapter7.pdf

Comment: You need to consider the possible values of $A$, $A$ cannot be 1. The smallest value of $A$ is 2, and as Henry showed below, it is $(.01)^2 = 0.01$. In other words $P(A = 2) = .01$

Comment: The possible values of $A$ are $\{2,3,4,5,6,8,11,12,14,20\}$.

Comment: If you have computer aid, you can also try the probability generating function approach which is easy to code: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%280.00971z%2B0.458z%5E2%2B0.21z%5E3%2B0.113z%5E4%2B0.111z%5E10%2B0.0797z%5E11%2B0.0156z%5E40%29%5E2

Comment: "the prob. distribution of event A" You mean *the distribution of the random variable A*, A is not an event.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

Consider each of the $10$ possible values for $A$

For example $P(A=2)=P(X=1 \text{ and } Y=1)=0.1^2$ while $P(A=3)=P(X=1 \text{ and } Y=2)+P(X=2 \text{ and } Y=1)=0.1\times 0.4+0.4 \times 0.1$

Comment: Thanks. I updated my question. It had my implementation. But I cannot find the value of $A$ in the result. It only return the distribution value

Comment: @user2938494 The distribution of $A$ can be described using a table. It is **not** one value.

Comment: Yes. I know. I want to show the prob. of $A$ such as the table of $P_X$

Comment: It means what is first value of the result, $P(A=1)$ or $P(A=2)$, in convolution it is $P(A=2). However, what is next values and so on...

Comment: I think it is $P(A=2); P(A=3) ;P(A=4)....$

Comment: Since x and y both take values from 1 to 40, A can be between 2 and 80. These are the appropriate A values for the probability vector you got.

Comment: @laugh: Let see my update. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.